# how to get and set the number of row in a tableView in javfx

Tags: javafx

I tried to manipulate a tableview and I need to know how to get the number of row that I have in a table view?
And how to set them?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? The rows of the table view are represented by the data you get from `table.getItems()`. So the row number is effectively just the index of the item in that list. Where do you want this information and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: What I mean is that: if my table contain 3 row filed with data, so I want to get 3

Comment: You mean the number of *rows*, not the "number of row", I think (i.e. the row count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of rows in the table is just

```
table.getItems().size()
```

You can't set this directly, of course, you just change it by adding and removing data from the table.

Comment: I try it but it gives me 0, even if I initialised table with 4 rows

Comment: Edit your question with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates that.